# Python 3 regex from file

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to parse a barely formated text to a price list.
I store a bunch of regex patterns in a file looing like this:

```
[^S](7).*(\+|(plus)|➕).*(128)
```

When i attempt to verify whether there is a match like this:

```
def trMatch(line):
  for tr in trs:
    nr = re.compile(tr.nameReg, re.IGNORECASE)
    cr = re.compile(tr.colourReg, re.IGNORECASE)
    if (nr.search(line.text) is not None): doStuff()
```

I get an error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in go
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in trMatch
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 224, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 292, in _compile
    raise TypeError("first argument must be string or compiled pattern")
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern
```

I assume it can't compile a pattern because it is missing 'r' flag.
Is there a proper way to make this method to cooperate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `r""` syntax is not mandatory for working with regular expressions - this is just a helper syntax for escaping fewer characters, but it results in the same string. See [What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/7586)

I'm not sure what `trs` is in your code, but it's a good guess that `tr.nameReg` and `tr.colourReg` are not strings: try to debug or print them and make sure they have the correct value.

Comment: all those attributes resolve as strings: >>> trs[9].nameReg
'(✖|x|х).*(256)'. So i'll have to escape everything in the csv?

Comment: @Pytoon - I have a [working example here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolSsvMTc1KDVdwVZBXePRnGk1FTUXWzX1tDSMTM001bnyioASRal6yfm5BZk5qRpQ1TogMU93P/8gV2fHYFdNrsw0BY28Ir3i1MSi5AwN9QqgbnVNhcxihbz8EgW//LxUTSuFgqLMvBINdX9vRXXN//8B) with very similar code to yours. Can you post a complete example in the question, including how you initialize `trs`? I'm not sure what you mean by "escape", but it already looks like a valid regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out re.search doesn't omit null patterns as I assumed. I added a simple check if there's a valid pattern and string to look in.
Works like charm